# Wordpress ERROR :reCAPTCHA verification failed. Please Try Again

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha, google-signin

I'm new to wordpress, literally the first time using it, and now i am frustrated because i cannot even get in on the page even as an admin because of the error on the title.

So here's how it went :

i wanted to add social login for my web
i install nextend social login and use the google platform for it
i did every step right (i made sure of it, there's a list of steps in the nextend i just simply follow it)
i copy the secret id and cope, i verify it and i wanted to test it out
so i log out of my user, and i don't even see the google button to login (maybe because i haven't add it (i thought it's automatic))
and so i went to login using user and password turns out it gives me an error

ERROR :reCAPTCHA verification failed. Please Try Again.

i have searched at google, youtube and nothing seems to work, please help

Note : i cannot get into my account

[image: Here's the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** Examine what other plugins you have installed.
Perhaps one of them is interfering e.g if you have cache plugin, you might want to clear your browser cache and try again and/or disable the cache plugin entirely

**Option 2:** Disable and re-install
If you have access to the host account, you can disable and re-install the plugin via phpmyadmin or ftp as shown in the following article.
https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-wordpress-plugins/

Comment: hi, sorry for late reply, it was the first option that matters i tried to deactive all my plugin and turn it one by one to detect the problem. thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your hosting login to WP through there to your admin panel.
2. Go to your google reCAPTCHA account get keys and paste them to your reCAPTCHA plugin on Wordpress again.